# Why is the Talmudic style so Confusing?

Tags: talmud-gemara

why is the Talmud is written in such a confusing manner. Every other discipline in the world is taught in such a way as to make it as easy as possible to understand. If you learn mathematics for example, they first teach you addition then subtraction. Once you master that, you go on to multiplication, division, algebra, geometry, etc.

There is a clear order, building up from simple to complex and it's written in such a way as to be as easy as possible to understand. On the other hand, the talmud is written in a seemingly chaotic fashion. The very first mishna says:

"when do we read the shema?.. When the Kohanim enter to eat their teruma..."

Who? What? What Kohanim? What shema?! First tell me about the source of the mitzva of shema. Where does it come from. What is it? Instead the mishna jumps right in with a confusing mix of information. furthermore the talmud is constantly going off on tangents many of which are totally unrelated to the current tractate.

why is it written like this?

for example, If I want to teach physics in a clear way, I'd start with newton's laws of motion and then after a semester when this is fully clear I'd move up to waves and other more complicated stuff, then maybe optics or electromagnetism then thermodynamics,etc then quantum theory. (and even within newton's laws, I would start from basic and move up to complex). I would not  start with newton's laws then throw in  some electro-magnetism stuff and a little quantum mechanics all at once as this would totaly confuse every one. One must start with ONE most fundamental subject and explain it fully then move on to another subject which builds on that.

Comment: It's confusing because you're not used to it. Every other discipline in the world is taught in such a way...if you learn mathematics, first they teach you addition then subtraction. Etc.

Comment: To echo @SethJ, your example of the first Mishna is actually very beautiful in its succinctness and in the amount of information it carries with it in so few words.

Comment: lots of information yes, but to teach a beginner about the mitzva of shema, you first teach the relevant verse than move up to the purpose of shema, etc. but to jump in with discussion of kohanim/ tuma/tahara, etc. seems like you need to know the entire shas mishna just to understand the first mishna. this is not how it would be taught in a university course.

Comment: @R.Sebag why would you expect it to be taught as it would be taught in a university course?

Comment: doesn't this beg the question of WHY one is learning the gemara? If I just want to learn the mitzvah or the halacha, I don't go back to the gemara and watch the development of argument. The skill being taught is completely separate so the mode of instruction has to be separate as well.

Comment: @yoelbecause this is the way to make things understandable. I dont know of any mathematics course which starts with addition and throws in some calculus and geometry before teaching substraction and multiplication.

Comment: @R.Sebag why would you expect the goal of the Gemara to be the same as the goal of a university course?  I put it to you that the Gemara does not just give over the information - it forcibly teaches you to *think*.

Comment: see my question. i added to it an example

Comment: If you want to know what the halacha is, there are better ways to do it than by diving into the talmud.  You study talmud to understand the *process* and the *arguments* moreso than to get the *answer*.

Comment: yes. but one can present the arguments without having to go all over the place delving into subject and bringing lots of side points from everywhere. it's like one big interconnected web

Comment: allow me to submit another reason. it's confusing because you aren't supposed to start with it. if you just jump in, you haven't taken the prereqs.

Comment: In line with what several others have said, I believe there is the assumption when you open Mishna that you are familiar with _halacha_ at least as stated by the Torah, and as practiced as well. There are plenty of assumptions about familiarity with agriculture, government, and other aspects of life as well. Similarly, in a university course on physics it is often reasonably assumed that students have familiarity with lower school physics.

Comment: Mishna was originally tool for encapsulating a compressed form of the Oral Torah in a form that lends itself to verbatim preservation either in human memory or on paper. I don't think it was meant to be, by itself, an ideal form of pedagogy for any level of student. That would have been left to one's teacher.

Comment: Actually, your example doesn't make a whole lot of sense. In many instances, especially in the sciences, teachers throw in some "teaser" information about more complex ideas and principles to keep the students interested and to show them where all their studies will be leading them eventually.

Comment: teasers. yes, but delving into the complexity of the subject smack in the middle no way. @yoel you can teach people how to think without this method. if you ever learned university physics you'll see that you'll need to think quite hard to grasp the concepts and solve the problems, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that the Oral Law had been left as oral teachings for quite some time, until the Mishnah began to put things down.

At the time the Mishnah was written, an average Jew would have been raised knowing that he recites Shema twice daily, and he would have seen Kohanim waiting till nightfall to consume *terumah*. So the Mishnah is filling us in on the nitty-gritty that we may not have known just from observing normal practice, assuming we have some background.

It's also been suggested that part of the goal was to keep a great deal of the Oral Law oral, hence the Mishnah is just some rough notes. It wasn't intended as a standalone text for a novice.

Comment: many of the tangents the talmud and mishna go off in have NOTHING to do with the current tractate. look at perek beis shamai in berachos for example. likewise in the gemora you can go from berachos to tuma/tahara to kilaim etc.

Comment: That's a different issue. The Talmud's goal was to put down as much law and lore as they could, and if tangents are how they got there, so be it. It's still been suggested that keeping it difficult was part of how to keep it partly oral; it's also been suggested that some of what we see are notes from the lecture hall, and occasionally things went on tangents. By the way sometimes things fit better than you think; the destruction of the Second Temple is in a chapter called "those damaged", in the tractate on divorces; Sotah immediately veers into self-control for *men* (not "blame the woman")

Comment: ... and the chapter in Pesachim about how family dynamics play out with regards to the Korban Pesach starts getting into general discussions of family dynamics, and our relationship with G-d.

Comment: `It's also been suggested` By whom?

Comment: This is a great answer. The crux of it is that the Talmud isn't intended for someone landing from Mars and trying to learn from scratch; rather, it is assumed that the reader is embedded in a Jewish community and already knows these practices from doing.

Answer (score 7):

Pirkey Avos 5:22

> Five years is the age for the study of Scripture. Ten, for the study of Mishnah. Thirteen, for the obligation to observe the mitzvot. Fifteen, for the study of Talmud.

Talmud seems difficult because it is expected that you will have spent five years studying the Scripture on which it is based and five years studying the Mishnah itself before diving into the Gemara in all its complexity.  Besides this, you will have been actively engaged in learning about the practical aspects of the commandments from the age of three on.  In other words, it's not a first year class.

Comment: But it's a class for 15 year-olds according to this Braisa.

Comment: @DoubleAA yeah, and they've been in school since five!  Three, really, as far as learning about mitzvos is concerned.

Comment: Who hasn't been in school since five?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm sure if one dedicated their life to physics and started with the basics at five, at fifteen they'd be ready for advanced classes.

Comment: That's not the case here though. You only start Gemara at 15. (Plus this kind of explanation of your answer should be [edit]ed in.)

Comment: @DoubleAA it seems pretty clear to me, and I don't think it needs any explanation.  You start at five.  Gemara seems confusing to the OP because it's ten years in to learning.

Comment: How does 5 years of Chumash prepare you?

Comment: @DoubleAA see [these](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26659/why-is-the-talmudic-style-so-confusing/26664#comment60993_26659) [comments](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26659/why-is-the-talmudic-style-so-confusing/26664#comment61000_26659), and [Shalom's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26663/1304).

Comment: Are you expecting future readers to approach your answers after receiving a basic education in the other comments and posts?

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess I thought these points were obvious.

Comment: Since they are evidently not, I will edit my answer, though I would prefer succinctness, personally.

Comment: yoel, you have a good point. but even within the talmud itself it follows this confusing pattern. so it seems you need to learn the talmud a few times first before even beginning to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's important to take into consideration the manner in which the Talmud was composed. It has never been a secret that the authors of the Talmud were many and various, ranging over a period of some three centuries and spanning an area that ranged from Palestine in the West to Babylonia in the East. It is, in essence, a commentary upon a similarly authored compilation (the Mishna having been composed by multiple individuals over a period of a century at a minimum), and one which incorporates other teachings - both those that are anonymously authored and those that were attributed, however correctly or incorrectly, to specific individuals.

The compilation of the Talmud involved stitching these different texts together on the basis of theme and content, sometimes coupling a section with another because they share a keyword or because they both refer to the same sage. The "stitching" comprises those anonymous portions that were written last of all, which link each sugya to its surrounding content and which provide a narratorial voice that questions and analyses the authenticity of traditions. As a piece of literature, this is already vastly different to other examples of human creativity, and cannot properly be compared to them.

When somebody wishes to learn mathematics, the teacher will begin with the most basic information and will increase in complexity as the student's skills develop. Likewise, if somebody wishes to learn halakha, (s)he will start with basic material and only approach the more difficult material once that has been mastered. Under no circumstances would somebody start with the Talmud if their intentions are to know the halakha. They start with the Talmud if their intentions are to know the Talmud, which is a field of study in and of itself.

Answer (score -3):

Basically: they didn't have the time, resources, and manpower to make the Talmud a careful, precise, and highly organized text.  So they didn't.

Try turning one page of Talmudic thought into careful, precise, ordered statements.  It requires a MONUMENTAL amount of work.  The Encyclopedia Talmudit has taken almost fifty years now to get to the letter Yud, and that is with fully-funded experts, in close contact, in a wealthy country, using computers and email.  Imagine trying to make breakfast or write down a poem in the year 600!, and then consider how impossible it would have been to turn the Talmud into a tidy encyclopedia back then.

Fortunately: Time was on our side.  Over many centuries, thousands of minds have poured over the Talmud and contributed to making it clearer and more consistent.  Rashi was a breakthrough, as was Tosfot, and now is Schottenstein.  Its a big task, but we've got a long time to work on it.

Comment: The Rambam made a "encyclopedia talmudis" (although he doesn't mention aggadata) all by himself less then 700 years later.  Mishnayos would be a lot easier in his style.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Its one thing to organize a work that does exist. But its another to organize a work, that hasn't even been created yet - ie while Struggling just to compile and record and assemble and create a huge body of information.  RAMBAM was only able to do what he did because the authors of Talmud did the first step, of just getting all the material down on a page.

And of course, Rambam left out basically all the rationales and arguments and proof-texts and minority opinions.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't think Rambam made an 'encyclopedia talmudis'. He made a listing of psaks.

Comment: @DoubleAA this comment is on Ben ‘s answer but I am tagging doubleaa because I enjoy his critical analysis of statements made on this forum. I feel as though a better outlook on the matter (of why the Gemara is so succinct), was because that they wanted to keep the oral law, oral! With this idea, the writhing down of the oral law was done in more of a “surface level” way so that the Torah won’t completely be forgotten. The penetrating depth of the Talmud must be passed down through the doros, whether through pilpul or mesora from rishonim and so on.